# Pandas: replace regex with string ending with tab not working

Tags: python, pandas, regex

I have the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Depth':['7500', '7800', '8300', '8500'],
                'Gas':['25-13 PASON', '9/8 PASON', '19/14', '56/26'],
                'ID':[1, 2, 3, 4]})
```

[image]

I want to add the word "PASON" to the end of any value in the Gas column that does not have it already, so that it ends up looking like this:

[image]

It should be a simple replace using Regex, but it doesn't work. Here is my  code:

```
df['Gas'] = df['Gas'].replace(to_replace =r'(\d+/\d+)(\t)(\d+)', value = r'\1 PASON\2', regex = True)
```

I've checked the Regex in a Regex checker, and it works fine there, but when I add it to Pandas it doesn't work. What am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you mean to match the TAB which separates columns? :) I guess you wanted `df['Gas'] = df['Gas'].str.replace(r'^\d+/\d+$', r'\g<0> PASON', regex = True)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply check for the substring 'PASON' and add if not present:

```
df['Gas'] = df['Gas'].where(df['Gas'].str.contains('PASON'), df['Gas'] + ' PASON')
```

giving

```
  Depth          Gas  ID
0  7500  25-13 PASON   1
1  7800    9/8 PASON   2
2  8300  19/14 PASON   3
3  8500  56/26 PASON   4
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply do this

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Depth': ['7500', '7800', '8300', '8500'],
    'Gas': ['25-13 PASON', '9/8 PASON', '19/14', '56/26'],
    'ID': [1, 2, 3, 4]
})

df['Gas'] = df['Gas'].apply(lambda x: x if x.endswith('PASON') else f"{x} PASON")

print(df)
```

which gives

```
  Depth          Gas  ID
0  7500  25-13 PASON   1
1  7800    9/8 PASON   2
2  8300  19/14 PASON   3
3  8500  56/26 PASON   4
```

If you only want to add PASON in those cases where you have digits

```
import pandas as pd
import re

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Depth': ['7500', '7800', '8300', '8500', '40404'],
    'Gas': ['25-13 PASON', 'Something PASON', 'AnotherValue', '12/34', 'NoDigitsHere'],
    'ID': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
})


df['Gas'] = df['Gas'].apply(lambda x: f"{x} PASON" if re.search(r'\d', x) and not x.endswith('PASON') else x)

print(df)
```

which gives

```
   Depth              Gas  ID
0   7500      25-13 PASON   1
1   7800  Something PASON   2
2   8300     AnotherValue   3
3   8500      12/34 PASON   4
4  40404     NoDigitsHere   5
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a simple in place modification with [`str.endswith`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.endswith.html) and [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df.loc[~df['Gas'].str.endswith('PASON'), 'Gas'] += ' PASON'
```

Output:

```
  Depth          Gas  ID
0  7500  25-13 PASON   1
1  7800    9/8 PASON   2
2  8300  19/14 PASON   3
3  8500  56/26 PASON   4
```